# Deploying QtQuick 2.0 Application with SVG Plugin

Tags: plugins, deployment, qml, qt5, qt-quick

My application is built with Qt 5.0.1 and QtQuick 2.0. It runs just fine in Qt Creator, but I'm having trouble getting it to deploy properly. I copied the executable (Release version) into a directory on my desktop called "Project Deployment" and added a bunch of DLL's (release versions, not debug), my QML files, and the SVG images.

Everything works fine except the SVG images, which don't show up at all. I converted one of them to a GIF, and it displayed perfectly. So clearly, I'm not setting up the QT SVG plugins properly.

I've got this in main(), right after QApplication app is defined:

```
QStringList libPaths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
libPaths.append(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/plugins");
app.setLibraryPaths(libPaths);
```

In the `Project Deployment/plugins` folder, I've placed `iconengines/qsvgicon.dll` and `imageformats/qsvg.dll`. In the `Project Deployment` folder, I have the Qt5Xml.dll (because I read somewhere that because SVG is in XML format, it uses that dll).

I am completely out of ideas (and internet resources). Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the SVG plugin (QSvg.dll) through Dependency Walker, you find that it relies on `Qt5Svg.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be placed in the `imageformats` folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files\AppFolder\imageformats\qsvg.dll`

More info here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/deployment-plugins.html